# .htaccess redirection with query string on url

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, hosting

I have a website `www.example.com/blog/abc.` I need it to redirect to `www.example.com/blog/a.php?a=abc`

**Below is my .htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ blog/a.php?a=$1 [R=301,L]
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: So what’s the actual question/problem …?

Comment: @misorude Please read the question.

Comment: _“What am i doing wrong ?”_ - oh that’s an easy one: You completely neglected to describe what the problem is.

Comment: If this is asking for error.log guesses, probably a neverending rewrite loop.

Comment: I guess you are getting a Redirect Loop error with your rule since the pattern and destination path of your rule are same. Put the following condition above your `RewriteRule` line to fix this.

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/blog/a\.php$`

Comment: Or use a different regex pattern so that it doesn't match your rule's target uri `^blog/((?!a\.php).*)$` .

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/?$ blog/a.php?a=$1
```

Instead of:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ blog/a.php?a=$1
```

Comment: Tried www.example.com/blog/try , It redirects to the following url - http://example.com/home/example/public_html/blog/a.php?a=try

Comment: try get rid of `RewriteBase /`

Comment: the rewrite is rewriting the final bit correctly `blog/a.php?a=try` the base looks like its getting your full server folder `/home/example/public_html/`